# Data structure for visualizing organizations and individuals using Gephi?

Tags: data-structures, visualization, edges, graph-visualization, gephi

Using Gephi, I'd like to visualize how members of different organizations are related.
My source material basically consists of a list of organizations and their members:

```
Organization 1
Individual 1
Individual 2
Individual 3
Individual 4

Organization 2
Individual 5
Individual 1
Individual 6
Individual 7
```

Sometimes an individual shows up in different organizations (i.e. Individual 1 in this example).

**Questions:**
1) How should I convert this information into edges so that the relationship between and within organizations becomes evident?

2) I also have some meta-information about organizations (type) and individuals (sex), that I'd like to use in the visualization (to affect the layout, color etc.). How do I arrange this in relation to the edges?

ps. I'm *not* a CIA agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) here is a GML-file with the setting above.

```
graph
[
  Creator Gephi
  directed 0
  node
  [
    id "1955"
    label "Org1"
    graphics
    [
      fill "#ff0000"
    ]
  ]
  node
  [
    id "1956"
    label "Org2"
    graphics
    [
      fill "#ff0000"
    ]
  ]
  node
  [
    id "1957"
    label "Person1"
  ]
  node
  [
    id "1958"
    label "Person2"

  ]
  node
  [
    id "1959"
    label "Person3"
  ]
  node
  [
    id "1960"
    label "Person4"
  ]
  node
  [
    id "1961"
    label "Person5"
  ]
  node
  [
    id "1962"
    label "Person6"
  ]
  node
  [
    id "1963"
    label "Person7"
  ]
  edge
  [
    id "54566"
    source "1955"
    target "1957"
    value 1.0
  ]
  edge
  [
    id "54567"
    source "1955"
    target "1958"
    value 1.0
  ]
  edge
  [
    id "54568"
    source "1955"
    target "1959"
    value 1.0
  ]
  edge
  [
    id "54569"
    source "1955"
    target "1960"
    value 1.0
  ]
  edge
  [
    id "54571"
    source "1956"
    target "1957"
    value 1.0
  ]
  edge
  [
    id "54570"
    source "1956"
    target "1961"
    value 1.0
  ]
  edge
  [
    id "54572"
    source "1956"
    target "1962"
    value 1.0
  ]
  edge
  [
    id "54573"
    source "1956"
    target "1963"
    value 1.0
  ]
]
```

If you think it is easier, you can make a excelfile with two columns, "source" and "target" and export as a csv, and then import it into gephi:

```
Org1;Person1;
Org1;Person2;
Org1;Person3;
Org1;Person4;
Org2;Person1;
Org2;Person5;
Org2;Person6;
Org2;Person7;
```

then apply a layout algoritm to make the layout. Start trying with Yifan Hu or Force Atlas.

2) If you want to add meta information, use the GML-format mentioned above and include the data you want:

```
 node
  [
    id "1"
    label "Person1"
    sex "Male"
  ]
```

You can then use ranking and partition-settings to apply certain colors/sizes depending on the attributes provided.