# Generate a friend graph on gephi with python dictionary

Tags: python, gephi

I'm trying to use gephi (http://gephi.org/) to generate a friend map.  Currently my data is stored in a dictionary that looks like:

```
{id1 : [friend_id, friend_id2 etc],
id2 : [friend_id3],
id3 : ... }
```

What is the structure of data that gephi needs for the graph that looks like this 
https://gephi.org/wp-content/themes/gephi/images/screenshots/layout2-mini.png

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can choose between multiple. The easiest is to use a Excel-chart and save it as CSV. 
In the first column put person1id and in column2 person2id:

```
 person1id  person2id
 Adam       Maria
 Maria      Ben
 Ben        Adam
```

You can also use any of these formats: https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/
The easiest to generate from you data would probably be GML or GraphML.

Also see my answer at this question outlining how to use GML: [Data structure for visualizing organizations and individuals using Gephi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592370/data-structure-for-visualizing-organizations-and-individuals-using-gephi/10772810#10772810)